# Obsfucated Text -- Minds of the masters

Tags: word

You are applying for a job at Company X. You are an agent from Company Y, bitter rivals with Company X (they sell variables at low prices!). Your job is to sabotage Company X with your company's newest innovation: the subscript manipulator! (e.g. $x_n\to n_x$).

Your mission: Infiltrate Company X posed as a prospective employee, get into the Variable Room (VR, for short), throw your device into the Set Constructor, and leave. You must pass the interview with flying colors, else they wont accept you.

After a brief debriefing, you are ready. You know the routine--the only variable is the interview question. You put on your best suit (black 3-piece with a crimson red tie) and drive to the interview.

---

Once at the designated office, you are greeted by a man wearing a simple polo shirt and a baseball cap. This is definitely the man you need to see (he told you so). He sits down, and motions for you do to the same. You sit across from him, sweating ever so slightly. He has a broad smile slapped on his face. Did he know your real aim? You only pray that he doesn't.

Smiling, he reaches under his desk and hands you an ancient computer with only the most basic functions. It has a single document on the screen, containing these characters:

> ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒
>   ▀▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
>   ▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
>   ▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀
>   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

"You have ten minutes. I wish you luck, Mr(s). `$LASTNAME`," he says, still smiling. He promptly walks out of the room and locks you in it. Your immediate response is to browse the internet for an answer, but to no avail: there is no Wi-Fi! Curses! After wasting a minute, you divert your energy into solving the problem. An unsuccessful minute later, you look into the other files contained on the computer. The only file you manage to find is a small `.txt` file like this:

```
FILENAME: your_hint.txt
DATE: ??/??/???? ??:??:??
-------------------------
iF icon(cab):

(EOF)
```

Stumped, you analyze the 'hint' and continue with the puzzle.

---

Can you solve the puzzle?

Hint:

> The answer is a single word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hint is:

> iF icon(cab) which is an anagram for **Fibonacci**

The single word is:

> **Box** (sideways) which is obtained by shifting each row into alignment.  Each row is shifted by using the series of prime numbers (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,etc)
>
> ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▀▀▀▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
> ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

Comment: Great! Any ideas as to the hint?

Comment: Great work! \*accepts\*